# Excel VBA Value wildcards are not returning a result for find a bold function

Tags: wildcard

In range M:M there is text in each cell. I need to Bold ever time the date format yyyy-mm-dd appears in each cell in the range. I have been using the following formula to do the same operation for defined text but i am unable to get it to work when i am using wildcards.

I am not properly defining

```
Dim rCell As Range, sToFind As String, iSeek As Long
Dim myWord As String
myWord = "202#[-]##[-]##"
sToFind = myWord
For Each rCell In Range("M1:M1000")
iSeek = InStr(1, rCell.Value, sToFind)
Do While iSeek > 0
rCell.Characters(iSeek, Len(sToFind)).Font.Bold = True
iSeek = InStr(iSeek + 1, rCell.Value, sToFind)
Loop
Next
End Sub
```